# Change object axes on rotation Threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

This has probably been asked, but I haven't found an answer yet.
Is it possible to rotate object with it's axes? By that I mean, can you, for example, have a person model, and have it's face "look" straight where the z axis is, then rotate that person around y axis for some degrees and now for that object z axis still be straight where he "looks"/faces?

```
if(left) {
    cube.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0.25, 0), Math.PI/16);
} else if(right) {
    cube.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, -0.25, 0), Math.PI/16);
}
```

Comment: updated the post with what I have so far. It doesn't do the trick though

Comment: have you looked into quaternions? https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Quaternion

Comment: damn, that's a hell of a rabbit hole I'm getting myself in to. Thank you

Comment: haha. No problem, good luck!

Comment: The axis should be a normalized vector.

Comment: See this thread and examples: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14496